# Is it possible to change the active link color without CSS in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, nav, bootstrap-5

I haven't used HTML in quite some time, and this is only my second time attempting to create tabs, so I may be going about this in the wrong way.

However, as it is, the link text uses the primary bootstrap color by default (blue), and turns to a darker blue when active.
I can change the text to a singular color, but I can't figure out if there's a way to make it change for the active tab. Like, say, I want the text to be grey, but black when that tab is active.

I only have access to HTML, so I'm not sure if this is possible, or if I'm just doing it wrong.

```html
 <!-- navigation -->
    <nav>
     <div class="nav nav-sm bg-faded rounded" role="tablist" style="font-size:15px;">
      <a class="nav-item  nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-one" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-one" aria-selected="true" style="">link 1</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-two" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-two" aria-selected="false" style="">link 2</a>
     </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- end navigation -->
```

Comment: i dont think its possible to do it without css

Comment: What do you mean "without CSS"? Everything related to style/color in HTML is done using CSS. Do you mean change using only Bootstrap classes and not custom CSS? Do you mean using JavaScript to manipulate the CSS?

Comment: Sorry, it was difficult to word the question because I'm aware everything uses CSS, and since coding is more of a hobby I'm unaware of all the proper terminology. I can't use custom CSS or CSS styles like in the answer I did receive below, but can use inline CSS within my HTML, if that makes sense. Usually I just work it into my HTML, but can't seem to figure out if there's a way to change the color of active tabs this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the standard Bootstrap CSS file rather than building your own using SASS, then you can override Bootstrap styles by defining styles in the head section of your HTML page.

In the code snippet below, I’ve overriding Bootstrap’s black for the `active` tab with purple and the other tabs with red and green for the hover state.

You just need to be sure to use enough [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity to override the existing style, or use `! important`.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
    .nav-tabs .nav-item.show .nav-link, .nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
        color: purple;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-color: #dee2e6 #dee2e6 #fff;
    }

    a.nav-link {
        color: red;
    }

    a.nav-link:hover {
        color: green;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but unfortunately what I am working with does not read CSS, even in the HTML page. I am unable to use it, hence my question.